# docker deployment mosquitto error：Address in use and Address not available

Tags: mosquitto

How to solve this problem

[image]

```
[root@iZf8z8ooxm0rsr5hsejg0iZ config]# docker exec -it mosquitto sh
/ # mosquitto -v
1711804289: mosquitto version 2.0.14 starting
1711804289: Using default config.
1711804289: Starting in local only mode. Connections will only be possible from clients running on this machine.
1711804289: Create a configuration file which defines a listener to allow remote access.
1711804289: For more details see https://mosquitto.org/documentation/authentication-methods/
1711804289: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1711804289: Error: Address in use
1711804289: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1711804289: Error: Address not available
```

Comment: You can not start a second instance of mosquitto inside the container, it's already running

Comment: Seems like `mosqito -v` is not exactly doing what you might expect.

Comment: You haven't explained what you are trying to do so we can't answer the question